# How can I open an epub+zip file on my S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I got some files that say "epub+zip" undrr Properties and I wanted to know how can I open it?

OS: 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ebook reader that reads EPUB files. Aldiko (http://www.aldiko.com/) is a great ebook reader that supports EPUBs. Or, you could rename the extension to zip and extract the file. Inside, you will see some folders. Within one of the folders are HTML files that can be viewed in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use kobo. It is an app for reading. I usually email myself the epub file then go into the email where the file is located on the right hand side there will be 3 little dots click that to save and then go into the kobo app and click the phones menu button to import the epub files to your kobo app and then it should show up in your kobo library.

Comment: Link to the app would be nice.